# how to loop through elements of array of <UnsafeMutablePointer> in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I am new to Swift and wanted to loop through an array of `MKMapPoints<UnsafeMutablePointer>` which I get from an `MKPolygon` by calling `myPoly.points()`.
However, I am stuck as to how to loop through every element of the C-Array of pointers.

```
for element in myPointsArray {}
```

does not work and I don't know how to determine the number of elements of this kind of array in Swift. Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`UnsafeBufferPointer` presents an unsafe pointer and a count as a collection so you can for..in over it, subscript it safely, pass it to algorithms that work on collections etc:

```
for point in UnsafeBufferPointer(start: poly.points(), count: poly.pointCount) {
    println("\(point.x),\(point.y)")
}
```

Comment: I got `Type does not conform to protocol SequenceType` error

Answer (score 2):

You can get the count of points from `MKPolygon.pointCount` property. And iterate `points` with traditional `for ; ; {}` loop:

```
let myPointsArray = myPoly.points()

for var i = 0, len = myPoly.pointCount; i < len; i++ {
    let point = myPointsArray[i]
    println(point)
}
```