# Working with UnsafeMutablePointer array

Tags: ios, swift, gpuimage, unsafe-pointers

I'm trying to work with Brad Larson's splendid `GPUImage` framework, and I'm struggling to process the cornerArray returned by the `GPUImageHarrisCornerDetectionFilter`.

The corners are returned as an array of `GLFloat` in an `UnsafeMutablePointer` - and I would like to convert that to an array of `CGPoint`

I've tried allocating space for the memory

```
var cornerPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<GLfloat>.alloc(Int(cornersDetected) * 2)
```

but the data doesn't seem to make any sense - either zero or 1E-32

I found what looked like the perfect answer [how to loop through elements of array of <UnsafeMutablePointer> in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27474967/how-to-loop-through-elements-of-array-of-unsafemutablepointer-in-swift) and tried

```
filter.cornersDetectedBlock = {(cornerArray:UnsafeMutablePointer<GLfloat>, cornersDetected:UInt, frameTime:CMTime) in
        crosshairGenerator.renderCrosshairsFromArray(cornerArray, count:cornersDetected, frameTime:frameTime)

    for floatData in UnsafeBufferPointer(start: cornerArray, count: cornersDetected)
    {
        println("\(floatData)")
    }
```

but the compiler didn't like the `UnsafeBufferPointer` - so I changed it to `UnsafeMutablePointer`, but it didn't like the argument list.

I'm sure this is nice and simple, and it sounds like something other people **must** have had to do - so what's the solution?

Comment: Did you see the lowercase f in <GLfloat>? The typo could be a failure reason.

Comment: Not at first!  But I did :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `UnsafeMutablePointer<GLfloat>` type translated from C can have its elements accessed via a subscript, just like a normal array. To achieve your goal of converting these to CGPoints, I'd use the following code:

```
filter.cornersDetectedBlock = { (cornerArray:UnsafeMutablePointer<GLfloat>, cornersDetected:UInt, frameTime:CMTime) in
    var points = [CGPoint]()
    for index in 0..<Int(cornersDetected) {
       points.append(CGPoint(x:CGFloat(cornerArray[index * 2]), y:CGFloat(cornerArray[(index * 2) + 1])))
    }
    // Do something with these points
}
```

The memory backing `cornerArray` is allocated immediately before the callback is triggered, and deallocated immediately after it. Unless you copy these values over in the middle of the block, as I do above, I'm afraid that you'll leave yourself open to some nasty bugs. It's also easier to convert to the correct format at that point, anyway.

Comment: splendid - that's how I will do it :-)

Comment: See ‘UnsafeBufferPointer’ solution before, it should be many times faster.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solution - and it's simple.  The answer was here https://gist.github.com/kirsteins/6d6e96380db677169831

```
var dataArray = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: cornerArray, count: Int(cornersDetected) * 2))
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is safe in this case. The backing memory for `cornerArray` is manually allocated right before this block is called, and manually freed immediately after. I believe that if you do this, you'll encounter memory corruption bugs. I've provided an answer that shows how to safely copy these values over into the format you want.

Comment: This is the fastest method and is safe, according to Apple’s documentation: “However, initializing another collection with an UnsafeBufferPointer instance copies the instances out of the referenced memory and into the new collection”

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
     var cornerPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<GLfloat>.alloc(Int(cornersDetected) * 2)

    filter.cornersDetectedBlock = {(cornerArray:UnsafeMutablePointer<GLfloat>, cornersDetected:UInt, frameTime:CMTime) in
        crosshairGenerator.renderCrosshairsFromArray(cornerArray, count:cornersDetected, frameTime:frameTime)

    for i in 0...cornersDetected
    {
        print("\(cornerPointer[i])")
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this.  cornersDetected is only defined within the closure, so you can't use it before the cornersDetectedBlock.  Other than the incorrect ordering of the code, I don't see anything different from what I already have